# How to automatically launch a program when a particular folder is opened

Tags: c, windows, security

I'm not exactly sure if this question has been asked because I couldn't find it but I want to created a mechanism such that that whenever you open a particular folder, it automatically launches a particular program.

That is, I open a folder, and the program launches prompting me for a password to proceed.

I'm running Windows 10, programming in C.

Comment: You should let us know for which operating system you want to do this. But this is most probably difficult do to in any system. Anyway what do you mean by "open a folder"? This can be a `cd folder` command in the shell or it can be opening the folder from a GUI.

Comment: What do you call exactly *open a folder* ? Open a folder in a file explorer (-> try to find a *hook*)? Open a folder in a specific application (-> add code to the app)? Open a file at any level under that folder ( -> oups, good luck for this last one ...)?

Comment: If you're doing this on Linux, [inotify](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=inotify&page=about&lang=en) is definitely the way to do this.

Comment: You should use the Windows's operating system's security model to restrict access (file/directory ACLs), not create your own.

Answer (score 0):

I think what u want is complicated.

To keep it simple:

The only thing that notices that a Folder is opening would be your OS so you would have write a program that monitors the messages send and received by your OS and tell it to act when the message to open the folder is sent.

Comment: If u just want to PW protect one folder there are allready alot of programs out there that can lock a folder.